# Simple Rails 4 migration throwing a flag on Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple migration here for my first Rails 4 project. This is the first migration in my project, on the very first model. I also tried doing:

```
rake db:forward STEP=1
```

but that did nothing, not even an error. Here is the migration:

```
class CreateOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :organizations do |t|
      t.string :org_type
      t.string :status
      t.string :name
      t.string :dba_name
      t.string :url
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the error I get on `rake db:migrate`.

```
undefined method `to_i' for []:Array/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:36:in `version'
```

That error is in the ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.version method, which simply calls `super.to_i`.

It must have something to do with the `schema_migrations` table. Right now it is blank. It's almost as I'm missing an initialization step.

Did I adopt too early, or am I missing something with 4? Please also note that all databases have been created and do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. Postgresql allows for versioned records. At least, that's what I `think` it is. Anyway, the `schema_migrations` table was created with it's one column `version` having a `dimension` of 1.

I thought I would just try to fool Rails by putting a zero in there. Well, Postgres wouldn't let me add the value! It complained in a manner similar to Rails, saying something about an `Array` having to be formatted a particular way. That was when I noticed the dimension.

I changed that `dimension` field on `schema_migrations.version` from a 1 to a 0. Then I re-ran the migrations and they went fine.

---

***UPDATE***

---

This was apparently a bug in `Rails 4.0.2`. Fortunately Rails `4.0.3` was released yesterday. Look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868939/why-are-all-of-my-tables-in-rails-4-postgres-being-created-with-dimension-of-1) answer for steps on how to overcome this issue.