# Why are all of my tables in Rails 4/Postgres being created with "dimension" of 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I'm running into a LOT of problems just trying to do basic model generations and migrations in Rails 4 with Postgres. I have the `pg` gem installed, version `0.17.1`.

In the beginning, I couldn't even run migrations without errors, because the `schema_migrations` table was created with the `version` column having a dimension of `1`. Once I manually changed it to zero, it worked fine.

Now, if I look at all of the migrations that resulted from me using the Rails model generator, I see that ***every single column***, with the exception of the `id` column in each table, was created with `dimension` of `1`.

Is there some default setting I need to change? Is this somehow correct and I am messing up something else? This is my first Rails 4 project, so I'm just trying to figure out why it would want all of those columns to default to an Array.

Here is one of my migration files:

```
class CreateCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :catalogs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :schema_name
      t.string :catalog_type
      t.boolean :billable

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this is from `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "catalogs", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name",         array: true
  t.text     "description",  array: true
  t.string   "schema_name",  array: true
  t.string   "catalog_type", array: true
  t.boolean  "billable",     array: true
  t.datetime "created_at",   array: true
  t.datetime "updated_at",   array: true
end
```

What in the heck!

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would typically run a `rails generate` command or show me a migration file for one of your models (`db/migrate/<date>_create_catalog_users` for instance)?

Comment: A new version of Rails just came out today, version 4.0.3. I just upgraded, generated a dummy model and voilá it's fixed. Where can I find the release notes and what's changed between minor releases? I can never find that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luck would have it, `Ruby on Rails v4.0.3` was released ***today***. I did the following:

1. Upgrade Rails
2. deleted `db/migrate/schema.rb`
3. Delete all 3 databases (dev, test, production)
4. ran `rake db:setup`
5. ran `rake db:migrate`
6. Looked at the new `db/migrate/schema.rb` to make sure it was OK
7. ran `rake db:test:prepare`

Sure enough, the problem is fixed in this new release. I couldn't find a record of the problem anywhere! It's been an issue for a few weeks. Anyway, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It may be your migration that specifies each column to be array